Computing the inverses of two linear maps
I have two linear maps $X: \mathcal{L}(G) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_q^k$ and $Y: \mathcal{L}(2G) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_{q^n}$, where $G$ is a divisor of the rational function field $F_q(x)$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is the Riemann-Roch space of $G$. Currently, I am stuck on computing the inverse maps $X^{-1}$ and $Y^{-1}$. I know I need to use the bases of the two Riemann-Roch spaces and solve linear combinations but I am unsure on exactly how to do this. Any help would be much appreciated.
Edit:
$X$ is defined as follows: For a function $f \in \mathcal{L}(G)$, $f(P_i)$ is computed on $k$ rational places $P_1,..,P_k \in F_q(x)$.
$Y$ is defined as follows: For a function $f \in \mathcal{L}(2G)$, $f(P)$ is computed on a place $P \in F_q(x)$ of degree $n$.

Welcome . What is $K$? And what is the definition of $X$ and $Y$?

I explained what $K$, $X$, and $Y$ were in the post.

No. There are many function fields, there is not "the function field". Also, $X,Y$ could be any linear maps as it seems, since you didn't define them, then how are we supposed to answer the question how to compute their inverses?

I edit the post with the definitions of $X$ and $Y$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are linear mappings, they can be converted into matrices, in which case the inverse matrices would correspond to $X^{-1}$ and $Y^{-1}$

My idea for converting $X$ to a matrix is creating a $k \times k$ matrix $X$ where each entry $X[i,j] = f_i(P_j)$ for places $P_1,...,P_k$ and $f_1,...,f_k \in B_1$, where $B_1$ is a basis of $\mathcal{L}(G)$. My idea for converting $Y$ to a matrix is creating a length $n$ vector $(G_1(P),...,G_n(P)$ where $G_1,...,G_n$ is a basis of $\mathcal{L}(2G)$. Then, for each $G_i(P)$, calculate a linear combination of elements $\gamma \cdot g_1(P),...,\gamma \cdot g_n(P)$. This results in an $n \times n$ matrix $Y$.
